# Display column arguments of Class "table" in doc

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-sphinx, pyramid

I'm trying to generate my doc with sphinx but I got an issue with the detail of information display in the output doc.

My class

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    Text
)
from ...models.meta import Base

class A(Base):
    """
    **Class A*
    """
    __tablename__ = 'table_a'

    # Columns #
    id= Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    """Id of element A"""
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    """Description of element A"""
```

Base are defined like this

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

NAMING_CONVENTION = {}

metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=NAMING_CONVENTION)

Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
```

The output generate in the doc look like this for my Column.

```
 ### id() Id of element A


 ### description() Description of element A
```

How can I display the column type, nullable, primary_key, etc. in the doc?

Is it possible to parse this information?

****** **EDIT**  ******

It seems that the problem is linked with `Base` definition. I don't know why but If a remove `Base` from my class, the doc generating works perfectly.

Looking right now to find the right definition of `Base`.

**Environnement:**

Windows 8

Python 3.7

Framework pyramid 1.10.4

Sqlalchemy 1.3.8

Comment: Do you get `####` in the output? If you showed us a screenshot I think it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah the ### is in the output of the markdown but the problem is not there, the problem is that the information of my column is not parse. I don't think than a screenshot will bring more information

Comment: Is the output supposed to be markdown?

Comment: Yes for this example I use markdown, but the output can be html or anything else, in every case I don't get the information I would like to have.I've try singlehtml and it's the same result

Comment: How can this be reproduced? I don't have the definitions of the Base, Column, Text, and Integer classes. Are SQLAlchemy and Pyramid required?

Comment: Yeah sqlalchemy is necessary, I'm going to edit my question to add the dependancy of the class

Comment: @mzjn Have you been able to reproduce?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, but I have no solution. I noticed that if `A` does not inherit from `Base`, then the wanted output is produced. I don't know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Base was define by another programmer and i'm not sure what it's suppose to do. If I remove it, it works for the doc generation but not for the route call. I'm going to work on Base definition to find what's wrong. If you want to do an answer with that, i will give you +1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do something like this

```
for key, col in A.__table__.c.items():
   if key == 'id':
      print(col.primary_key) # True
```

Comment: I don't want to do a print I want to have the column when I generate the doc of my API with sphinx-doc

Comment: @Michael I see, you asked if there is a way to parse that information, which I have shown. In your case, why not manually fill in the docstring as such?

"""
Id of element A
nullable: False
primary_key: True
"""

Comment: Because if the information is already in the column definition, I don't know why I need to repeat them in the docstring.